# HostingEnvironment.MapPath returning wrong path

Tags: c#, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a web application.

In IIS, I have a site WEBSITE, and my application is run from a subsite APPLICATION owned by WEBSITE.

The physical path on the machine does not match what HostingEnvironment.MapPath is returning.

Say I want to get to path PATH:

```
"\Folder\Document.pdf"
```

The physical path to the application is:

```
"E:\WEBSITE\APPLICATION"
```

HostingEnvironment.MapPath(PATH) is returning:

```
"E:\WEBSITE\Folder\Document.pdf"
```

which is quite clearly wrong.

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was missing ~ from the path, to include the virtual path as well as the physical path. The path would be:

```
"~\Folder\Document.pdf"
```